# How to correctly DI HttpClient into FlurlClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, flurl

Registering a custom message handler doesnt seem to work with FlurlClient.

```
    .. other setup logic
    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the application services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The service collection.</param>
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ConsoleCorrelationIdHandler>();
        this.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>(services, "http://httpbin.org");

    }

    private void AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services, string url = null)
        where TClient : class
        where TImplementation : class, TClient
        => services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        })
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<ConsoleCorrelationIdHandler>(); // Appends CorrelationId to all outgoing HTTP requests.
```

Here i register a new HttpClient with a ConsoleCorrelationIdHandler, which adds a correlation id header to all outgoing requests.

```
public class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    private readonly IFlurlClient _httpClient;

    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
    }

    public async Task GetSomething()
    {
        var x = await this._httpClient.BaseUrl
            .AppendPathSegment("get")
            .GetJsonAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)); // Doesnt have CorrelationId header, which should have been added by handler.
    }
}
```

Now when GetSomething gets called, the IFlurlClient does have the base url of the registered httpclient, but the message handler doesn't get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down your fluent call and see what's happening:

```
_httpClient.BaseUrl
```

You now have a reference to a string. You've lost your reference to the client here.

```
.AppendPathSegment("get")
```

Here you're calling a string extension method that creates a `Flurl.Url` object and appends `get` to the path.

```
.GetJsonAsync();
```

Here you're calling an extension method on `Url` that creates a `FlurlRequest` and calls its `GetJsonAsync` method. With no reference back to the client you want to use, it's going to look for one using the registered [FlurlClientFactory](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#flurlclientfactory). Not finding one there, it'll create a new one.

In short, you lost your reference to your `FlurlClient` right at the beginning of that call.

Here's how to fix it:

```
var x = await this._httpClient
    .Request("get")
    .GetJsonAsync();
```